# Access properties in BeanFactoryPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I am trying to create something which will auto-create beans based on configurable properties (from `application.yml` and the like).

Since I can't just access the properties component like I normally would in the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`, I'm kind of stumped how I can access them.

How can I access application properties in `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`?

Comment: Not sure if this fits your scenario, but have you had a look at custom auto-configuration and property conditions?

Comment: I don't think that will work for my scenario. In my scenario, you may be creating multiple instances of the same class, and the bean names themselves are dynamically set in the properties as well. I don't see a way to accomplish that with the normal auto-configure route.

Comment: When you say 'auto-create' beans, to me that sound like you are talking about prototype beans.

Comment: This is for a testing framework where it can auto-create dockerize (and other) dependencies based on configuration (think of something like docker compose, but more advanced). They are fully formed and running, but there are a variable number of them that need to be named specifically by the user to be able to access them easily.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to access properties in a type-safe manner in a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` you'll need to bind them from the `Environment` yourself using the `Binder` API. This is essentially what Boot itself does to support `@ConfigurationProperties` beans.

Your `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` would look something like this:

```
@Bean
public static BeanFactoryPostProcessor beanFactoryPostProcessor(
        Environment environment) {
    return new BeanFactoryPostProcessor() {

        @Override
        public void postProcessBeanFactory(
                ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
            BindResult<ExampleProperties> result = Binder.get(environment)
                    .bind("com.example.prefix", ExampleProperties.class);
            ExampleProperties properties = result.get();
            // Use the properties to post-process the bean factory as needed
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've been hunting for how Spring does that for a while now. I'll give it a try and let you know. I think that'll probably do the trick.

Comment: @Andy Wilkinson Is there any way I can get a Bean from ConfigurableListableBeanFactory with all dependencies injected. I am trying to get `RestTemplateBuilder `, but some exception happened since 'No default constructor found' for RestTemplateAutoConfiguration.

Comment: Is the `Binder` API available in Spring MVC?

Comment: @trebor `Binder` is part of Spring Boot.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't want to use the solution above that used an `@Bean` producer method since it's contrary to the recommended approach of annotating a class with `@Component` and picking up via component scanning. Fortunately it's straightforward to do that by implementing `EnvironmentAware`:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ConditionalDependencyPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor, EnvironmentAware {
  /** Logger instance. */
  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConditionalDependencyPostProcessor.class);

  /** Spring environment. */
  private Environment environment;


  @Override
  public void setEnvironment(final Environment env) {
    environment = env;
  }
  ...
  private boolean hasRequiredProfiles(final DependencyInfo info) {
    final Set<String> activeProfiles = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(environment.getActiveProfiles()));
    for (String profile : info.requiredProfiles) {
      if (!activeProfiles.contains(profile)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

I should note what did NOT work: trying to autowire an `Environment` constructor argument. BeanFactoryPostProcessors require a no-argument constructor and don't support autowiring, which is itself a feature implemented by another post processor, AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.